# Like objective-C , how to write "valueForKey" in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
NSDictionary dic;
NSMutableArray array;
//Objective-C Code.
array = [dic valueForKey:@"Table"];  //"Table" is key in dictionary
```

How to write same code in Swift?

Answer (score 9):

There is no more `valueForKey:` in Swift, but there is a way to use `map` to achieve a similar, if not same, result.

If the objects in the collection are dictionaries:

```
let array = dic.map { $0["table"] as? String }
```

If the objects in the collection are objects:

```
let array = dic.map{ $0.table }
```

If you are using Objective-C collection types like `NSDictionary` in your example, then like others have said, you can still continue to use `valueForKey:`.

```
let array = dic.valueForKey("table")
```

Comment: Swift essentially took everything useful in Objective C and removed it

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
let array: AnyObject? = dic["Table"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple eg.

```
(dicDetail.valueForKey("name") as! String)
```

Comment: But it will not work now. I think swift3 will change the syntax for getting key value from Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var dict=NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: NSErrorPointer.null()) as NSDictionary

 var temp=dict["contactname"] as String

var tem=dict.valueForKey("contactname") as String
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation to your code, showing how it solves the problem and why. This will help others who see your answer in the future, and make your answer more valuable to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You will better get the idea of how you can deal with Dictionaries in Swift

```
let employees = json["employees"]! as [[String : AnyObject]]
```

Next step is to loop the employees array and print the firstName and lastName.

Keep in mind that we are looping an array of dictionaries. Meaning that in order to get the String values from firstName and lastName we need to unwrap the optionals first:

```
for employee in employees {
  let firstName = employee["firstName"]! as String
  let lastName = employee["lastName"]! as String

  println("employee: \(firstName) \(lastName)")
}
```

Build, run and you should see:

```
employee: John Doe
employee: Anna Smith
employee: Peter Jones
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code. It might help in what you need.

```
var dictData = Dictionary <String,Any>()
var arrDictData = Array<Any>()

// Will store value for key in dictionary.
func storeData ( strName: String , strAge: String ) {
        dictData["name"]=strName
        dictData["age"]=strAge
        println("dictData: \(dictData)")
        storeInArray(dictData)
    }

    // Will store value of dictionary in array.
    func storeInArray ( dict : Any ) {
        arrDictData.append(dict)
        println("arrDictData: \(arrDictData)")
    }

    // Will return count of array.
    func resultArray() -> Int {
        println(arrDictData.count)
        return arrDictData.count
    }

    // This function will return value in label.
    func arrDictResult( dictKey: String, rowIndex: Int) -> String {
        var dataTemp = arrDictData[rowIndex] as Dictionary <String,Any>
        var val = dataTemp[dictKey] as String
        return val
    }
```