# Not getting syntax for value for key with object at index in array in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I am working on **Swift 3.0** in which I have taken an array, Now I want to get the value from a particular index with value for key from a dictionary. I tried multiple ways but still not able to find the solution.

For reference in Objective C we have to use this

> [arrGroupList objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@""]]

I want its equivalent in **Swift 3.0.**

Any help will surely be appreciated!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Like objective-C , how to write "valueForKey" in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689035/like-objective-c-how-to-write-valueforkey-in-swift)

Comment: valueForKey is a method of NSDictionary. So cast to it and use it

Answer (score 0):

```
let val = arrGroupList[0]
print(val["YYZ"])
```

Comment: This is not what the question about, you don't get `airports` from an array

Comment: If the array also consists a dictionary like i have asked then how i can be able to get it????

Comment: please : put your array to see what you want exactly

Comment: "messageList":[
{"chat_id": "2327", "conversation_id": "2357", "sender_id": "269", "receiver_id": "270",…},
{"chat_id": "2326", "conversation_id": "2356", "sender_id": "269", "receiver_id": "270",…},
{"chat_id": "2302", "conversation_id": "2332", "sender_id": "270", "receiver_id": "269",…},
{"chat_id": "2301", "conversation_id": "2331", "sender_id": "270", "receiver_id": "269",…}
]
}

Comment: arrGroupList[0]["keyYouWant"]

Comment: in this case :

var val = ["messageList":[
    ["chat_id": "2327", "conversation_id": "2357", "sender_id": "269", "receiver_id": "270"],
    ["chat_id": "2326", "conversation_id": "2356", "sender_id": "269", "receiver_id": "270"],
    ["chat_id": "2302", "conversation_id": "2332", "sender_id": "270", "receiver_id": "269"],
    ["chat_id": "2301", "conversation_id": "2331", "sender_id": "270", "receiver_id": "269"]
    ] ]




print(((val["messageList"])?[0])?["chat_id"]!)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// array of [[String:String]] Dict
let myArray = [[String:String]]()


let first = myArray.first
let second = myArray[1]
let last = myArray.last
```

In your case (assuming that `arrGroupList` contains [String: String]), it should look like this:

```
let firstValueInFirstDict = arrGroupList[0]["myKey"]
```

Note That `firstValueInFirstDict` is an optional String.

**EDIT**:
If you are getting `Any` instances instead of `[String: String]`, you should check it:

```
    guard let firstDict = arrGroupList[0] as? [[String: String]] else {
        return
    }

    let firstValueInFirstDict = firstDict["myKey"]
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hi ,i tried  "let firstValueInFirstDict = arrGroupList[0]["myKey"] " this one but getting error

Comment: run time or compile error? what does it say? are you sure that you used a right key (instead of keeping "myKey")?

Comment: its compile time error "type any has no subscript members"

Comment: oh, so what's the type of your array? (option + click on it to see it) is it [String:AnyObject]?

Answer (score -1):

```
let item=newdata[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

        //let newitem=String(item["name"])
        cell.textLabel?.text=String(describing: item["name"]!)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text=String(describing: item["city"]!)
```